# Minimizing "buzzing" in a recording

Tags: audio-recording, mixing

I made a rock recording of myself and a few of my friends playing, however since our iPhones were dead and we really wanted to record, so I was forced to borrow and setup a camcorder from the Cafe we were playing in.

Although the sound in the Cafe was really good, I think I must've had the gain on the camcorder mic turned up too much because the sound came out with almost a buzz which accompanies the sound.

The only thing I can compare it to is a bad recording of a Nirvana song I found, [Talk to Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uukOdFdyqVQ).

Is there a fix for this? I really want this to sound good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good will not be on the table for this. Slightly less buzzy? maybe. Check out Izotope RX - there is a de-hum and de-clip module. These may help.